# canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagram"

Tags: ios, flutter, social-media

I've followed all guidelines by declaring the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes under Info.plist file but it return failed for those strings. I've no idea on it. Appreciate if someone could help it :)

```
<dict>
   <key>NSBonjourServices</key>
   <dict>
      <key>0</key>
      <string>_dartobservatory._tcp</string>
   </dict>
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
      <string>facebook</string>
      <string>whatsapp</string>
      <string>twitter</string>
      <string>instagram</string>
      <string>instagram-stories</string>
      <string>linkedin</string>
   </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Errors:**

[image]

**Info.plist**

[image]

**Info.plist**

[image]

Comment: Is your app given permission to access internet?

Comment: yes, it work fine with other features that require internet connection to fetch data @AmithaMohanan

Comment: That's weird. Make sure you modify the correct plist file, in case you have several targets

Comment: Yea, I don't get it as well. I put the array under the general Info.plist that placed out of the Runner folder @ArikSegal

Comment: @ArikSegal thanks for the head up. Yea it works after I placed under Info-Debug.plist that stored under Runner. But, do you know how to share a text together with image for Facebook? I'm using appinio_social_share package. It worked fine on Android :(

Answer (score 0):

While adding `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` you need to edit `Info.plist` for all schemes. So you need to edit `Info.plist`, `Info-Debug.plist` and any other Info.plist if you have created any different scheme for iOS project.

As per documentation of [appinio_social_share](https://pub.dev/packages/appinio_social_share) some applications support image for iOS and some applications don't support even if you provide it.